# Idle timeout in tcp connection

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I have some clients and a server on windows (I am using winsock for both client and server), the server is waiting for clients to get connected to it via tcp,
while waiting for almost 5 minutes after establishing connections with the incoming clients and waiting for others, the connection is getting closed from the server side, and recv is returning error code 10053, on the client side recv is returning 0.
I tried to set SO_KEEPALIVE option in both server and client, but it is not working. the server is hoted on a VM on AWS.

Here is the server code: for turning on socket option in listening socket

```
struct addrinfo hints1;
    memset(&hints1, 0, sizeof(hints1));
    hints1.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints1.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints1.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    struct addrinfo* bind_addres;
    int port2 = port + 3;//8081+3=8084 is the port of the tcp connection
    char port2_str[10];
    sprintf(port2_str, "%d", port2);
    getaddrinfo(0, port2_str, &hints1, &bind_addres);//this server is running on port 8080

    SOCKET tcp_socket = socket(bind_addres->ai_family, bind_addres->ai_socktype, bind_addres->ai_protocol);
    if (!ISVALIDSOCKET(tcp_socket))
    {
        cout << "\n socket not created=>" << GETSOCKETERRNO();
    }
    int enableKeepAlive = 1;
    setsockopt(tcp_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (const char*)&enableKeepAlive, sizeof(enableKeepAlive));

    cout << "\n binding the socket==>";
    if (bind(tcp_socket, (const sockaddr*)bind_addres->ai_addr, (int)bind_addres->ai_addrlen))
    {
        cout << "\n failed to bind the socket==>" << GETSOCKETERRNO();
    }
```

here is the server code for turning on the socket option in the connected sockets:

```
struct sockaddr_storage client_address;
                    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client_address);
                    SOCKET client = accept(tcp_socket, (sockaddr*)&client_address, &client_len);
                    int enableKeepAlive = 1;
                    setsockopt(client, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (const char*)&enableKeepAlive, sizeof(enableKeepAlive));
```

the code at the client side for socket is:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    struct addrinfo* bind_address;
    int port2 = port + 3;
    char port2_str[10];
    sprintf(port2_str, "%d", port2);
    //cout << "\n port of the server2 is==>" << port2_str;
    getaddrinfo(ip_address.c_str(),port2_str, &hints, &bind_address);
    cout << "\n tcp connection port is=>" << port2_str;
    SOCKET tcp_socket = socket(bind_address->ai_family, bind_address->ai_socktype, bind_address->ai_protocol);
    if (!ISVALIDSOCKET(tcp_socket))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed. (%d)\n", GETSOCKETERRNO());
        //return 1;
    }
    int enableKeepAlive = 1;
    setsockopt(tcp_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (const char*)&enableKeepAlive, sizeof(enableKeepAlive));
```

After turning of SO_KEEPALIVE, the connection is getting broken after almost 5 minutes, the connection is getting disconnected at the server side.

The windows firewall may be on, on the host maching for server. and the server is hosted on AWS VM.
Now how should I keep the connection alive?

Comment: The connection should be kept alive by baking in ping-pong message that gets exchanged between the peers, every minute or so, as part of the protocol?

Comment: but after turning on SO_KEEPALIVE, the connection is still breaking. why?

Comment: It seems you might need to disable `SO_KEEPALIVE` and have that functionality as part of your own application-level protocol. Default new connections to have the keep-alive functionality turned *off*, and have a special message to enable it when needed. You will probably still need some kind of timeout for that message too though.

Comment: If there is a NAT in the middle, TCP keepalive will only maintain the connection between one of the ends and the NAT, not across the whole path. And the keepalive may not count towards the inactivity timeout associated with the connection in the NAT. Or other similar firewall shenanigans. Hence the "protocol keepalive" suggested by @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Also the default keepalive interval may be longer than the inactivity timeout on some firewall in the middle. Have you fiddled with that?

Comment: so that means i have to add  my own mechanism to tell the server to keep the conection alive? but if keep alive time is around 2 hours, so why is connection getting broken in 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider, at least.

First, SO_KEEPALIVE, with default timings, doesn't even kick in until 2 hours have passed with no activity. Yes, that's right -- it's two *HOURS*, not minutes, not seconds.

Oftentimes, other entities in the connection will drop the connection much quicker than that.

Second, keepalive works on the TCP level. Applications usually have their own timeouts -- they don't want a connection to remain open when nothing is happening.

In general, protocols that have valid use cases for having an open but seemingly idle connection might implement an "heartbeat"-kind of scheme: they will still ditch connections where nothing is happening (to catch network failures or crashed clients that still have an open connection), but support a special "heartbeat"/"ping" packet/command that effectively does nothing, but you can send it every few seconds or so, to prevent the connection from being "idle".

If such a heartbeat is not defined in the protocol, chances are the protocol designers didn't see a need for it.

Comment: Funny side note: in a client that I'm working on, I've actually added some special hacks to the logging, so the "heartbeat" messages aren't logged. The server has rather short patience and requires heartbeats to be sent every few seconds, so they would clutter the logs for no useful reason... so yes, heartbeats are a real thing.

Comment: I get you, but if keep alive time is 2 hours, why is server disconnecting in 5 mins without being explicitly told so? because error code 10053 shows network error.

Comment: @AnchitRana Start by checking the logs at the other end of the connection, what happen in the program that has the other end of the connection? If nothing happens, what happens in that systems firewall? What happens in your firewall? What happens in the routers, switches and firewalls between the two systems?

Comment: at the client side, recv call returns with code 0 that means, connection was gracefully disconnected by the client, and for the firewall, client is connected with the college wifi, using cloudfare VPN, and server is on aws. is windows firewall interfereing or antivirus firewall?

Comment: @AnchitRana That means the *server itself* closed your connection, otherwise you would get an error.

Comment: I told you server has no logic to cut off the connection after 5 mins, it is either done by tcp or windows firewall

Comment: "*SO_KEEPALIVE, with default timings, doesn't even kick in until 2 hours have passed with no activity*" - this can be adjusted on a per-socket basis using [`WSAIoctl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sio-keepalive-vals)

Comment: @AnchitRana "*I told you server has no logic to cut off the connection after 5 mins, it is either done by tcp or windows firewall*" - or anything else on the network that is sitting between the client and server. Like the router, for instance. Routers don't typically like long-lived connections that are sitting completely idle, they take up resources that could be better used for more active connections. If you turn on `SO_KEEPALIVE`, use `SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS` to make the keepalive interval *shorter* so they are transmitted more often.